# Cannot convert value of type Int to expected argument type Bool

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to filter Firebase query results with three conditions:

```
let posts = snapshot.childSnapshots.map {
                    Post(snapshot: $0)
                    }.reversed().filter {
                        post?.isGlobal == dataFilter && (self.dependents.contains($0.postedBy) || self.currentUser?.uid == $0.postedBy)
                }
```

The first condition `(post.isglobal == datafilter)` must be met. Then, I want to filter posts further when either one of the remaining two conditions are met.

The above code returns an error: `Binary operator == cannot be applied to operands of type NSNumber? and Int`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

EDIT: the `dataFilter` variable is defined as a global variable within the viewcontroller class:

`var dataFilter = 0`

Comment: Comparison is done with  `==`, not with `=`

Comment: If I change it to `==` I get error `Binary operator == cannot be applied to operands of type NSNumber? and Int`

Comment: try `(post?.isGlobal.intValue ?? 0) ==` or just unwrap you optional post before accessing its isGlobal  intValue property

Comment: Thanks Leo! That worked. What did that do? Did that cast it to Int, and then sets it to 0 if the value is not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just unwrap your optional post and access its isGlobal intValue property, NSNumber has an intValue property that returns an Int that you can compare against your dataFilter (Int) value. Or use '??' nil coalescing to unwrap your optional binding and at the same time provide a default value for it in case of nil.

So if you unwrap your post object:

```
post.isGlobal.intValue == dataFilter
```

Or using the optional biding with the nil coalescing operator:

```
(post?.isGlobal.intValue ?? 0) == dataFilter
```